# java JUnit instruction at start of tests and end of tests

Tags: sql, junit

Is there any annotations available in JUnit (or other) which could launch instruction only at the start of tests and at the end? For example: start SQL session at the start of tests and close it at the end. @Before and @After - is no an option(((
Extract from tests:

```
public class HibernateTest {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionfactory;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    Session session;
    Transaction tx;

//  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException, SQLException, DatabaseUnitException {
        session = sessionfactory.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String sql_categories = "ALTER SEQUENCE categories_category_id_seq1 RESTART WITH 1";
        String sql_projects = "ALTER SEQUENCE projects_project_id_seq1 RESTART WITH 1";
        String sql_donations = "ALTER SEQUENCE donations_donation_id_seq RESTART WITH 1";
        String sql_clear_donations= "delete from donations *";
        String sql_clear_projects = "delete from projects *";
        String sql_clear_categories= "delete from categories *";
        session.createSQLQuery(sql_categories).executeUpdate();
        session.createSQLQuery(sql_projects).executeUpdate();
        session.createSQLQuery(sql_donations).executeUpdate();
        session.createSQLQuery(sql_clear_donations).executeUpdate();
        session.createSQLQuery(sql_clear_projects).executeUpdate();
        session.createSQLQuery(sql_clear_categories).executeUpdate();

    }

    @After
    public void setDown() throws MalformedURLException, SQLException, DatabaseUnitException {
        session.close();
        tx.commit();
    }

//  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @Test
    @ExpectedDatabase(
            value = "classpath:ExpectedAddedCategories.xml",
            assertionMode = DatabaseAssertionMode.NON_STRICT//Не проверять все поля. Только те что надо в xml файле, а не все в базе
            )
    public void testAddCategories() {
        Category cat = new Category("sport");
        Category cat2 = new Category("art");
        Category cat3 = new Category("video");

        session.persist(cat);
        session.persist(cat2);
        session.persist(cat3);
    }
}
```

This code actually does not work. Eclipse just freezes and does not even end one tests (I have showed only one test)

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you cannot use `@Before` and `@After`? That's the classic JUnit way of having code run before/after a test case.

Comment: I have tests for work with database. Each test does some action. I want to start session (one session) at start of tests and close it at the end. But not open/close after each test since it will cause delays. Bytheway I tried to open/close sessions with eclipse. My tests just freezed(((

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start it once per class, you can use [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and [@AfterClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html). If you want something more advanced you might want to look at [@ClassRule](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/ClassRule.html) also.